# How to link external website to internal javascript page

Tags: javascript, php, networking, dns

I have a website lets call it example.com , it is hosted at an external hosting provider. On the site I have a page http://example.com/msg.php that needs to reference a JavaScript from an intranet site lets say running on example_intranet.com, so I have a script reference like..

```
 <script src="http://example_intranet.com/js/messaging.js" type="text/javascipt">
```

I'm aware of cross-domain security issues and have setup the necessary CORS on the example.com site and pages.

When you visit http://example.com/msg.php from OUTSIDE the company network (example_intranet.com) everything works as expected, but when you visit the same page from within (INSIDE) the network the page doesn't appear to resolve the javascript include ..

any suggestions on how to fix this?That is to be able to have the reference javascirpt work from inside the network.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a DNS issue, not about code. The intranet URL domain likely resolves to a different "internal" IP address when you are on the company network, and when you are outside it resolves to a public IP address.

**Theoretical scenario:**

> When you are in the company network, the intranet URL gets resolved to
>   a local IP, like 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x. SO when you visit your page on
>   the external host your machine is trying to find the javascript file
>   using that internal IP, but it might be looking for it inside the
>   network of the external host, and won't find it.

As an experiment, try changing the path to your javascript file to use the public IP of that intranet URL instead of the domain name.

Comment: I tried when I use http://1.2.3.4 (where this is is the public facing IP address) from inside same thing noting happens,  if I try to go to http://1.2.3.4 which should resolve to the intranet site from inside nothing happens.  This is definitely a dns issue just not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: You will also want to look at the "Net" or "Network" tab of your browser developer tools. Firefox, Chrome, IE all have them. On this tab you can see if that javascript file is being loaded or if it is a 404. Just to narrow down if the problem is really about the JS file being included or not.

Comment: Also, what happens if you copy the path to the javascript file and paste it into your browser? Can you see the code?

Comment: In either case when I copy the IP url or domain url directly into any browser inside the network it just hangs and never returns,  it's clear it can't find the route,  I'm just clueless how to add the route to our ap,  if that's even the right way

Comment: You should talk to whomever controls DNS for your company. Where I work they do some odd stuff with internal/external IPs. Your DNS person may have helpful insight.